# mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification Consumes Memory

Tags: ios, core-data

I have two NSManagedObjectContext, one for ui and one for background tasks. I'm trying to merge changes to UIcontext whenever the background one changed. But whenever I call

```
mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:notification
```

It just start eating memory (will goes up to 1GB on simulator) and cause a crash.

of course I setup a notification:

```
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(coreUpdateFromApp:)
                                                 name:NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification
                                               object:nil];
```

and also tried doing the merge in main thread, etc. No luck!

I found out that URIRepresentation is causing the issue. For some reason it's keep being called. (by apple's code not mine)

Note that I let it run for under a sec and it uses 64.95MB it will grow pretty fast with same call tree. If I keep it running it would crash the osx as well!

[image: Profiler result]

Comment: Not an answer, but any reason why you are not using child-parent context concurrency modes? Much simpler to manage than thread-confined contexts.

Comment: @LeoNatan The app is not written by me, I inherited. And there is already much relaying on this not worth changing it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is `object:nil`. You are listening to an endless echo of notifications.

You need to specify a specific context object to listen to notifications from.

Comment: I tried, no difference. Calling mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification once will cause the issue.

Comment: Just uploaded the result

Comment: This looks like CPU profiling. You can profile memory allocations as well.

Comment: This is actually memory allocations, by call tree. (first column showing memory allocated by tree)

Comment: At the end of the tree, it just keep allocating CFString for some sort of URI!

Comment: Finally I found the issue, Google Analytics SDK!

Since GAI (Google Analytics for iOS 3.0) is using Core Data the code was getting notification from their changes as well. Per Apple doc app should crash at that point but in this case there was no error nor exception. But filtering out their changes from notification did fix the issue.

Comment: Mojtaba, this is very helpful... I am experiencing the same issue. How did you handle filtering out GA calls from the notification?

Comment: @MiMo When you register for `DidSave` notifications, make sure to specify your context as the object. If you have several contexts you want to listen to, register multiple times.

Comment: How did you filter out @Mojtaba any example ?

Comment: @Tejas simply set the managed object context as object when registering for notification

Comment: @Mojtaba It was not working for me. I found another way which worked for me like magic. Please see my answer tot his question for it.

Answer (score 0):

The Problem here is, Since Google Analytics also using core-data we are intercepting the endless notifications fired by Google Analytics as well.

Setting object to non-nil value didn't work for me. Found another way and it worked for me as magic.

Inside your observer I have selector method as below

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(managedObjectContextDidSave(_:)), name: NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification, object: nil)
```

and,

```
func managedObjectContextDidSave(notification: NSNotification) {
    if notification.object?.persistentStoreCoordinator != self.persistentStoreCoordinator {
        return
    }
    //do remaining task here.
}
```